# How to get the Default Account and Profile Id in apex while community is running?

Tags: community, salesforce-id

I have two active communities. Both community have different settings. I have  set default Account and Profile Id in Community Settings. I also enabled Auth. Providers to Login via Gmail/LinkedIn. Now I want to use that same default Account and Profile Id while registering via Gmail/LinkedIn.

Does anyone know how we can get default account and profile Id in apex(Registration handler apex class)?

Comment: Are you using standard community or community plus licenses?

Comment: I am using community plus licenses.